# Disable internet access for testing ionic app but still serve files from localhost

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework

I have an app that I'm testing on localhost via `ng serve`, and want to test the app offline.

I know in dev tools I can disable network access, however, this also prevents the files being served from localhost.

Currently, the only way I have found to test the app offline whilst still serving the files from localhost is simply to enable flight mode on my own computer, however, is there another way to achieve this?

Example screenshot, running `ng serve` whilst network is disabled
[image: Ng serve whilst network disabled in chrome]

Comment: Did you find out a good way to test this?

Comment: Not really, working on native I quite often use an emulator to test on android device and flight mode to test offline, but a little tedious still. Or could just disconnect device wifi when testing on web

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right path, but definitely there are alternatives to achieve the same results. The other possible ways I can think of:

1. Changing `Internet Proxy Settings` to point to a non-existent server, will block all your outgoing traffic but localhost.
2. Block outgoing traffic with `Firewall`.

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks. I had been hoping for something a little easier (e.g. some sort of setting that could be toggled on/off in chrome, but will investigate extensions to see if any can toggle specific proxy settings or firewall to achieve the same effect)